# Populating correct data in Angular and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am creating an angular template that will be used to show only one set of logos per page on a wordpress micro site - multiple pages, one logo per page with its variations. The data.json info is mostly url's of the variations. My conundrum is how to write the javascript that will correctly populate the relevant data. I thought maybe compare the page title to the logo_name (from json file) is a good condition to set a for-loop, but I'm not sure how to write the rest of the js, also not sure where in the controller.js to place the code. Here is a fiddle that does not link properly for some reason, the js shows the idea I am going for but obviously does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/roob/qpzt5akp/2/
Here is the controller:

```
            var brandApp = angular.module('brandApp', []);

            brandApp.controller('brandingContr', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
                $http.get('./js/data.json').success(function(data) {
                    $scope.logos = data;

                    var data=JSON.parse(data);
                    var logoName = data.logo_name[i];

                    var pgTtl=document.querySelector('title').innerHTML;
                    var dataLength = data.length;

                    for (var i=0; i<dataLength; i++)
                        {
                            if (logoName === pgTtl) 
                                {
                                    $("#wrappr").append();
                                }           
                        }


                });
            }]);
```

Below is the JSON data. Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
            [{ "logo_name" : "LA Times Core Logo",
                    "assets": {"display_logo" : "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/2015-latlogo-300x37.png",
                                    "blk_jpg" : "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/15LAT_Core_logo.jpg",
                                    "blk_png": "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/15LAT_Core_logo.png",
                                    "blk_eps" : "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/15LAT_Core_logo.eps",
                                    "wht_png" : "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/15LAT_Core_logo_White.png",
                                    "wht_eps" : "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/15LAT_Core_logo_White.eps"}
            },
            {   "logo_name" : "LA Times Media Group Logo",
                "assets": {"display_logo" : "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/wp-content/themes/lat-branding/img/15_LAT_MediaGroup_Logo.jpg",
                                    "blk_jpg" : "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/15_LAT_MediaGroup_Logo1.jpg",
                                    "blk_png": "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/15-LAT-Media-Group-Logo1.png",
                                    "blk_eps" : "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/15_LAT_MediaGroup_Logo1.eps",
                                    "wht_png" : "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/15-LAT-Media-Group-Logo-W1.png",
                                    "wht_eps" : "http://events.latimes.com/lat-branding/files/2015/08/15_LAT_MediaGroup_Logo_W1.eps"}
            }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle with the code you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/qpzt5akp/6/

There's some code in there to make it work with jsfiddle, but it should be obvious. Main thing: Don't use ng-repeat. No need here.

Here's your controller:

```
angular.module('brandApp', [])
    .controller('brandingContr', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('./js/data.json').then(function(data) {
            var logos = JSON.parse(data);
            var pgTtl = window.title; // or document.querySelector('title').innerHTML;      
            var matchingLogos = logos.filter(function(it,ix,arr) {
                return it.logo_name === pgTtl;
            });
            if(matchingLogos && matchingLogos.length > 0) {
                $scope.logo = matchingLogos[0];
            } else {
                //handle case for no logo found here.
                //Maybe a default logo, this would continue Promise
                //Throwing an error here would reject the current Promise.
            }
            return $scope.logo;  //Continue Promise
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, so simple too. If you dont mind me asking the last function has 3 parameters (it,ix,arr) yet only one (it) is used in the function - just so I can understand this better.

Comment: it = current element, ix = index, arr = array being worked on. Many JavaScript Array functions follow this pattern in their callback functions. MDN is a great source for these sort of things: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Parameters

Comment: I need to update this post to help anyone else who comes across this: the .find() method is not compatible in internet Explorer. My site broke in IE, I need to go back hard-code all the pages until the method does become compatible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: I've updated the post with a more IE friendly version. I've also updated it to use Promises properly.

Comment: Fester I immensely appreciate your update, was not expecting it. I will test it on monday since i only got as far as half-way in the manual coding  :)  cheers

Comment: Unfortunately this ran into problems. When using the code above console throws SyntaxError: Unexpected token o at Object.parse (native). When I replace the var logos with the following: var logos = data;  then I get no error but nothing loads. Take a look at this link to see that error: http://events.latimes.com/branding/projects/la-times-book-prizes-logo/

Comment: also tried to put another fiddle together with a variation of above code, the fiddle seems to be tricky to set up angular template. It still shows the alternative I thought is simpler and would have to work but it loads nothing: http://jsfiddle.net/roob/vnggosbn/

Comment: from what I read on other posts the .get() method already parses the json, so the JSON.parse(data) line is parsing it json a second time, which throws the error. I am trying to make the logic work from the initial state but nothing is loaded, and theres no error either.

Comment: @roob You were headed down the right path. Not sure why you commented out the error handling code on your site, but here's the fix. I took the source in your controller.js and modified directly for this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t3wc7j80/

Comment: Again I appreciate your follow through. I followed your code in the fiddle and it still will not load for some reason. Does it have to do with commenting the error handling part? here's a test page where I applied the angular templates: http://events.latimes.com/branding/flipbook-test/

Comment: After some more poking n prodding I realized the break was elsewhere, glad to say your controller not only works but it also loads perfectly in IE 11. Thanks again, tremendous help