# Angular template disappears in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, internet-explorer-11

the Angular templating that I set up works fine everywhere except in IE 11. The files such as controller.js and data.json are being pulled in but when looking in IE dev tools all the template code such as curly braces are missing. Angular version 1.3 is used, doctype declaration is also the right one.
[Here is one of the pages](http://events.latimes.com/branding/projects/52/).

Any help is appreciated, hate the idea of hard coding the whole site just for IE.

Comment: There is the error `TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'` in the IE console. It appears here `$scope.logo = logos.find(...)`

Comment: Unfortunately, IE does not support the `Array.prototype.find()` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: wow what a bummer, I thought that method is pure javascript which should work everywhere. Is there an alternative? I need the template to sort through a json file and pull the right data, here's the original problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639428/populating-correct-data-in-angular-and-json

Comment: `Is there an alternative?` - sure, here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find there is the code sample that shows how to implement the `find` method if it doesn't exist. See the `Polyfill` paragraph.

Comment: thank you, but then why are the curly braces missing?